# Add a column dependent on another column and a subset (using the tidyverse)

Tags: r, dplyr, dataset

I have the following data set of stock data (as a tibble)

```
Open  Volume   Ticker
<dbl>  <dbl>    <chr>
1106.  10       AAL.L
1086.  30       AAL.L
1043.  9        ABF.L
1055.  2        ABF.L
1048.  90000    BT-A.L
1077.  8000     BT-A.L
```

Using the dplyr package I would like to obtain this data set, with the average volume for a given Ticker.

```
Open  Volume   Ticker  AvgVolume
<dbl>  <dbl>    <chr>    <dbl>
1106.  10       AAL.L    20
1086.  30       AAL.L    20
1043.  9        ABF.L    5.5
1055.  2        ABF.L    5.5 
1048.  90000    BT-A.L   49000
1077.  8000     BT-A.L   49000
```

I will be doing this over 500000 rows so speed and efficiency is key (no for loops etc...)

I am new to the Tidyverse and would appreciate an explanation of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We group by 'Ticker', create the 'AvgVolume' as the `mean` of 'Volume' with `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Ticker) %>%
   mutate(AvgVolume = mean(Volume))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   Ticker [3]
#   Open Volume Ticker AvgVolume
#  <int>  <int> <chr>      <dbl>
#1  1106     10 AAL.L       20  
#2  1086     30 AAL.L       20  
#3  1043      9 ABF.L        5.5
#4  1055      2 ABF.L        5.5
#5  1048  90000 BT-A.L   49000  
#6  1077   8000 BT-A.L   49000
```

Comment: Thank you. So when you use group_by, then apply functions to the Tibble it always automatically separates these? 
Should I think of a data set that has been grouped as lots of subsets of data sets all in one "tibble"?

Comment: @HectorHaffenden  If you use `mutate` after `group_by`, the groups will be preserved unless there is a `ungroup` in the chain.  But, with `summarise`, one of the grouping variables gets removed in each summarise statement.   Regarding the second question, it is not clear

Answer (score 2):

Though you ask for a tidyverse solution and @akrun already posted one, I will post a base R way.

This is because your problem is textbook perfect for `ave`.

```
ave(df1$Volume, df1$Ticker)
#[1]    20.0    20.0     5.5     5.5 49000.0 49000.0
```

And just assign this output to a new column.

```
df1$AvgVolume <- ave(df1$Volume, df1$Ticker)
df1
## A tibble: 6 x 4
#   Open Volume Ticker AvgVolume
#  <dbl>  <int> <fct>      <dbl>
#1  1106     10 AAL.L       20  
#2  1086     30 AAL.L       20  
#3  1043      9 ABF.L        5.5
#4  1055      2 ABF.L        5.5
#5  1048  90000 BT-A.L   49000  
#6  1077   8000 BT-A.L   49000
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <-
structure(list(Open = c(1106, 1086, 1043, 1055, 1048, 1077), 
    Volume = c(10L, 30L, 9L, 2L, 90000L, 8000L), Ticker = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AAL.L", "ABF.L", "BT-A.L"
    ), class = "factor"), AvgVolume = c(20, 20, 5.5, 5.5, 49000, 
    49000)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```